# How to disable F1 for Help in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I often accidentally press <kbd>F1</kbd> when in GNOME which opens Help Center. Quite irritating.

I tried disabling it in key bindings but search through all the places they are stored in GNOME according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Keybindings and failed to find an <kbd>F1</kbd> binding for Help.

What have I missed?

Comment: Is this question still applicable? http://askubuntu.com/questions/58147/how-do-i-disable-the-help-f1-key

Comment: that answer doesnt work in latest ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 14.04

In the DConf editor, go to org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings

Assign the F1 key to some inoffensive function (e.g. set-spew-mark).

Comment: I don't have the "help" function as an option there (or anything else having F1 as the key stroke). I don't think I can add anything to the list either. Any hints?

Comment: You have to double-click and manually enter the reference key ('F1' in your case, with the quotes). If you assign F1 to a function listed there, that function (and not the help menu) will be performed when you press F1. Assigning F1 to a dumb function will disable your help pop-up.

Comment: Thank you. I did not get it first. You're right that assigning F1 to the existing unimportant function worked. A workaround but a good one.

Comment: How do I access / install / use the DConf editor?

Comment: @TomHale It's a program with a GUI, no special knowledge required. `sudo apt-get install dconf-editor`

Comment: Didn't work for me, on Ubuntu 18.04.