# Disable help browser keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, 18.04

On Ubuntu 18.04, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> opens the help browser.

In the keyboard shortcuts this isn't listed, and I haven't found a way to disable it.

I'd like to set <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> with some other command.

Comment: on my fresh install F1 opens help and Super + F1 opens activities window.  Show activities overview is listed under system

Comment: Hm, looks like F1 opens help, and Super + F1 is also opening help for me.

Comment: Related: (see comment) https://askubuntu.com/questions/58147/how-do-i-disable-the-help-f1-key#comment2106068_58147

Answer (score 2):

So far as I can tell there is no real way to disable it so we are going to reassign it using dconf editor.

First install dconf-tools

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

then launch dconf editor. From there navigate to org ->  gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings

assign it to something innocuous that doesn't have a keybind yet which will be denoted with a []. Your new shortcut should look like

```
['<Super>F1']
```

then click the checkbox at the bottom and now the help menu should no longer appear when you hit that key. I know this isn't a solution to just disable it however it works none the less also note that this set of hotkeys is for desktop window management,

Comment: Jarred, feels like this almost did it, but not entirely. I was able to reassign Super + F1 to an existing keybinding, however, I wasn't able to free up the combination to create a _Custom Shortcut_ in the keyboard settings.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get Help menu disabled and/or manually set the parameter.

**How I found the files with the settings**

Knowing where any configurations might be set is the first step. To figure out what files had the settings I needed, I ran the following commands:

Install locate program and update the database:

```
$ sudo apt install locate && sudo updatedb
```

Search for keybinding files with F1 or help in them:

```
$ locate keybindings | xargs grep -H -i f1
$ locate keybindings | xargs grep -H -i help
```

On my system the relevant outputs were:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.gschema.xml:      <default><![CDATA[['<Alt>F1']]]></default>
```

and

```
/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/01-launchers.xml:  <KeyListEntry name="help" description="Launch help browser"/>
```

**Possibly disable Help menu shortcut all together**

The keybindings for special keys seem to be set here:

```
/usr/share/gnome-control-center/keybindings/01-launchers.xml
```

See if commenting out the line

```
<KeyListEntry name="help" description="Launch help browser"/>
```

and logging out/in disables the help menu keybinding. Can you set a new keybinding for Super+F1 now? If so, is it possible to re-enable help so that F1 works again? If not, try moving on to setting the keybinding manually.

**Setting the keybinding manually**

Try manually setting the keybinding here:

```
/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings.gschema.xml
```

Look for the setting you want to assign and set it like this:

```
<key name="panel-main-menu" type="as">
  <default><![CDATA[['<Super>F1']]]></default>
  <summary>Show the activities overview</summary>
</key>
```

You may have to logout/in afterwords.

Good Luck!

Comment: Joshua, Thank you for these suggestions. I tried commenting out the _Launch help browser_ line without any success. I also tried setting the keybinding manually and that didn't work either.

Comment: did you find anything good when you did this? maybe another file where the config is set? $ locate keybindings | xargs grep -H -i f1