# How do I disable the Help F1 key in Ubuntu 18.04 or 19.04?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 19.04

This was asked a long time ago [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58147/how-do-i-disable-the-help-f1-key), but none of the answers provided work for Ubuntu after 18.04.

How do I disable the F1 keybinding for the "Ubuntu Desktop Guide"? I would like it to do nothing. Doing nothing would be a huge improvement on the unwanted disruption of Ubuntu Desktop Guide every time I accidentally hit F1 instead of Esc or F2, both of which do useful things.

If it could be made to do something else, in addition to not opening the Ubuntu Desktop Guide, that would be gravy.

Comment: What is your objective? Do you wish {F1} to be totally dead, or do you have something else in mind for {F1} to do? Please answer in your question by clicking [edit] instead of Add Comment as when new comments arrive they can push older comments off the page, while anything you add to the questions stays there.

Comment: What leads you believe https://askubuntu.com/questions/58147/how-do-i-disable-the-help-f1-key is locked?

Comment: Huh, I must have gotten it mixed up with another question. Sorry about that.